# Misalignment when putting two floating divs side by side (HTML)

Tags: html

I'm working on creating a power app that my logistics department will use and I wanted to create a PDF document that would act as a "ticket log". I'm using HTML to format it and this is the code I've figured out so far is below. Please excuse if the code is bad. Everything looks fine, except that my divs don't quite line up and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
        <html>  
            <head>  
    
                <style>  
                    #leftbox { 
                        float:left;   
                        width:50%; 
                        font-size:18px;
                        height:50px;
                        text-align:center;
                    } 
        
                    #rightbox{ 
                        float:right;  
                        width:50%; 
                        font-size:18px;
                        height:50px;
                        text-align:center;
                    } 
                    h1{ 
                        color:green; 
                        text-align:center;
                        font-size:30px;
                    } 
                    h2{
                        text-align:center;
                        font-size:20px;
                    }
                    h3{
                        float:left;
                        text-align:left;
                        font-size:18px;
                        height:20px;
                        width:50%;
                    }
                    h4{
                        float:right;
                        text-align:left;
                        font-size:18px;
                        height:20px;
                        width:50%;
                   }  
                </style>  
            </head>  
            <body>  
                    <h1>Name of my company</h1>
                    <h2>The address of my company<br>
                    Phone Number<br>
                    Transportation Services Receipt
                    </h2>
                    
                <h3>Sold To:</h3>
                <h4>Job Site:</h4>
                <div id = "leftbox">
                    Company Name
                    <hr style="width:90%">
                    Company Address
                    <hr style="width:90%">
                    Company City, State, Zip Code
                    <hr style="width:90%">
                </div>
                
                <div id = "rightbox">
                    Company Name
                    <hr style="width:90%;text-align:center;margin-center:0">
                    Company Address
                    <hr style="width:90%;text-align:center;margin-center:0">
                    Company City, State, Zip Code
                    <hr style="width:90%;text-align:center;margin-center:0">
                </div>
            
            </body>  
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `<h4>` to a `<h3>`.

Like this:
`<h3>Sold To:</h3> <h3>Job Site:</h3>`